# I'm receiving a signing error when trying to commit to git

Tags: git

I'm getting the following error when trying to commit to git.

```
gpg: skipped "3D750C77": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I have already configured git using `git config --global user.signingkey 3D750C77` but I'm still receiving this error.

Edit: This is the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`

```
C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/gnupg/pubring.kbx
--------------------------------------------------
sec   rsa4096 2021-02-17 [SC] [expires: 2023-02-17]
      FDBEBDF2D043F4473429C1F299CFB0A23D750C77
uid           [ultimate] clwm@github (github signing key) <29554879+clwm@users.noreply.github.com>
```

Comment: Your keyring only contains your public key. It needs your secret key to generate the signature.

Comment: @PaulWhipp How would I go about adding my secret key?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-gpg-key should put you on the right track.